# append iframe to div success but ready() not working

Tags: jquery

I have a onclick event like this:

```
function OnVisClicked() {
    $("#overlay").animate({opacity: "toggle",width: "3000px",height: "3000px"}, 300);
    $('<iframe />', {
    name: 'myFrame',
    id:   'mytFrame',
    width: 724,
    height: 535,
    frameborder:"0",
    scrolling: "no",
    allowTransparency: "true",
    src: "the link..."
}).appendTo('.myDiv').ready(function(){
    $(".myBigDiv").show();
}); 
    $("#someOtherDiv").css("display", "none");
}
```

Originally `myBigDiv` was set to `display:none`.
After I clicked on my button, the `myFrame` is successfully appended to `myDiv`. But `myBigDiv` was still `display:none`. I added a breakpoint inside the `ready()` but clearly the program didn't entered into it.

Addtional information after I got the answer and the solution:

My DOM cannot be fully loaded because of other web parts on the page, so `ready()` can never be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ready() function is called once only when the document is ready, http://api.jquery.com/ready/
I think you are looking for something else there like onload()

```
function OnVisClicked() {
    $("#overlay").animate({opacity: "toggle",width: "3000px",height: "3000px"}, 300);
    $('<iframe />', {
    name: 'myFrame',
    id:   'mytFrame',
    width: 724,
    height: 535,
    frameborder:"0",
    scrolling: "no",
    allowTransparency: "true",
    src: "the link..."
}).appendTo('.myDiv');

document.getElementById("mytFrame").onload = function() {

    $(".myBigDiv").show();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you, this is such a clever alternative solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the  attribute. If load must be used, either do not use .ready() or use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the window or to more specific items, like images.

`.ready( handler )` - A function to execute after the DOM is ready.

if you want append an iframe on the page load, try the code below.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('<iframe />', {
    name: 'myFrame',
    id:   'mytFrame',
    width: 724,
    height: 535,
    frameborder:"0",
    scrolling: "no",
    allowTransparency: "true",
    src: "the link..."
}).appendTo('.myDiv');

    });
```

If I understand your question right this should help you. If you have any issue let me know.

Answer (score 0):

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

- $(document).ready(handler)
- $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
- $(handler)

as **[Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** documentation says.

So you should not use this. you can use [`done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

```
.appendTo('.myDiv').done(function(){
    $(".myBigDiv").show();
```